# What is need of Assign/Deassign in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am here giving here 2 Verilog modules, which during simulation behaves same. But I don't understand that why to use `assign`/`deassign` in these modules, i.e. what is the difference between these 2 codes?

```
// Code 1 - Without assign-deassign
module dff (q,qbar,clk,reset,d)
  input clk, reset, d;
  output reg q, qbar;

  always @ (posedge reset, negedge clk)
  begin
    if(reset)
    begin
      q=1;
      qbar=0;
    end
    else
    begin
      q=d;
      qbar=~d;
    end
  end
endmodule

// Code 2 - With assign-deassign
module dff (q,qbar,clk,reset,d)
  input clk, reset, d;
  output reg q, qbar;

  always @ (negedge clk)
  begin
    q=d;
    qbar=~d;
  end

  always @ (reset)
  begin
    if(reset)
    begin
      assign q=1;
      assign qbar=0;
    end
    else
    begin
      deassign q;
      deassign qbar;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: In that only I am confused, using deassign the effect of assign can be removed. But I don't know where exactly both of them can be used???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original purpose of the procedural assign/deassign statements in your example was to separate synchronous logic from asynchronous logic in two distinct processes. It's also more efficient for simulation because the synchronous block does not have to check the reset signal every clock cycle. Modeling latches is also more efficient for simulation because because you don't have to check the enable signal every time the data changes, only when the latch is open.

This construct was synthesizable by early synthesis tools, but unfortunately, the **big** synthesis vendor decided not to support it, so no one uses these procedural constructs anymore.

Comment: Yes, but then suppose with assign deassign, if both events happen at the same time, then won't it give multiple driver error???  In 1st code this won't be the case.

Comment: procedural cont **assign** has priority over normal procedural assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The statements without `assign` are within a @ edge block, and are evaluated *only* at that edge. `assign` describes combinatorial continuous logic, and is by definition sensitive to its inputs.

In `Code 1`, `q` will change only when `clk` or `reset` changes, not when `d` changes.

`Code 2` has the effect that when `reset` is asserted, this block will continuously drive `q=1` (conflicting with any other driver) but when reset is negated, it will *stop* driving `q`.

This is actually more unusual use perhaps of assign - within an @edge block.

More conventional use would be like

```
assign out = (enable) ? data : 1'bz;
```

which will change whenever either enable or data changes.

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly, the procedural `assign/deassign` constructs are flagged for deprecation (at least in SystemVerilog), so it's better not to use them.

Comment: Yes I know about continuous assign statement, I was just wondered what's the use of procedural continuous assign-deassign in the code? & Where they can be used?