# verilog assigning to same variable not working

Tags: variables, crash, verilog, assign, hdl

I am having a strange problem with Verilog HDL.
I found in my code that if I multiply a variable by two, but then
assign that value to the same variable, it gets all messed up.
Sometimes, the simv program even crashes. I originally needed to do this,
because I had a for loop for shifting or rotating a certain amount. But,
then I found that not only shifting the same variable did not work, but
also, addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division does not work either.

So in my code example, if you set a to 16'b0001_0000_1010_0101, and b to 3,
then you get an output of 16'b0000_0000_0000_0000. Just note that I am ignoring b for now... I should get 16'b0010_0001_0100_1010... but something is going wrong.

So, this is my code file test.v:

```
// ALU module.
module test(in1, in2, out1);

input [15:0] in1;
input [15:0] in2;

output reg [15:0] out1;

// Variables for shifting right and for rotating left or right.
reg [15:0] shiftedValue;

always@(in1, in2)
begin

assign shiftedValue = in1;

assign shiftedValue = shiftedValue * 2;

assign out1 = shiftedValue;

// This display value is correct!
// but it's still wrong in the test bench.
$display("out1 == %b", out1);

end

endmodule

module testStim;

reg [15:0] a;
reg [15:0] b;
wire [15:0] c;

// create ALU instance.
test myTest(a, b, c);

initial
begin

a = 16'b0001_0000_1010_0101;
b = 3;

#10
$display("op1In == %b, op1Out == %b", a, c);

$finish;

end

endmodule
```

This is the output after running simv (I stripped out the erroneous garbage...):

```
out1 == 0010000101001010
op1In == 0001000010100101, op1Out == 0000000000000000
```

Thanks, 
Erik W.

Answer (score 3):

You have done what is called as **procedural continuous assignment**.

The difference between regular continuous assignments and procedural continuous assignments is this:

- Continuous assignment can only drive **wire/net** data type. Procedural assignment can drive only **reg** data type and not nets.
- Continuous assignment should appear **outside procedural blocks**(always, initial etc), while latter must be **inside procedural blocks**.
- Continuous assignment executes each time the **right hand side** expression changes. Procedural assignment depends on **sensitivity list** of always block.

As soon as the `always` block ends, the effect of `assign` statement is removed. You must add `deassign` statement to retain the values (which I think is not the real intent) or Just **remove** `assign` statement from the code. As shown below:

```
shiftedValue = in1;
shiftedValue = shiftedValue * 2;
out1 = shiftedValue;
```

More information about `assign`, `deassign` is available at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945764/what-is-need-of-assign-deassign-in-verilog), [this](https://geekwentfreak-raviteja.rhcloud.com/blog/2010/08/28/continuous-and-procedural-assignment-verilog/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641184/verilog-can-you-put-assign-statements-within-always-or-begin-end-statements) links.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense.

Comment: @Erik343 Kindly accept the answer to close this question.